# Excepción java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2 is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'

Tags: java, excepciones, javafx11

Tengo que implementar un método onClick para el siguiente botón:

```
<Button layoutX="150.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#FilterList" text="Buscar"/>
```

Pues bien, en el método que he implementado es el siguiente:

```
@FXML
private void FilterList() throws IOException{

    List<Player> players = guiApp.getController().getPlayersByName(searchId.getText());     
    displayPlayers(players);
}
```

GetPlayersByName simula una llamada a base de datos:

```
public List<Player> getPlayersByName(String name){
    List<Player> response=new ArrayList<Player>();

    for(Team t : this.getTeams()) 
    {
        response.add((Player) t.getSquad().stream().filter((o->o.getName().contains(name)|| o.getSurname().contains(name))));
    }
    return response;
}
```

El problema viene que al ejecutarlo obtengo la siguiente excepción:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3564)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8200(Scene.java:3492)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3860)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2 cannot be cast to class edu.uoc.baluocesto.model.Player (java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2 is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; edu.uoc.baluocesto.model.Player is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at edu.uoc.baluocesto.controller.Database.getPlayersByName(Database.java:214)
    at edu.uoc.baluocesto.view.gui.MainMenuController.FilterList(MainMenuController.java:137)
    ... 44 more
```

Y no tengo ni idea de como solucionarlo, ¿se les ocurre alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te pasa es que estás casteando un `Stream<Player>` (que es lo que retorna la llamada al método `filter()`) a `Player`. Evidentemente esto falla y de ahí la excepción que tienes:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2 cannot be cast to class edu.uoc.baluocesto.model.Player

Si lo que intentas es buscar todos los jugadores que coincidan con el criterio de búsqueda lo que debes hacer es después del `filter()` agregar un `collect(Collectors.toList())` para que te meta dentro de una lista todos los jugadores encontrados y luego agregarlos todos a la lista `response` con un `addAll()`.

Por otra parte te recomiendo siempre seprar el procedimiento de encontrar los jugadores del de agregarlos a la lista. Básicamente para que el código sea más legible.

```
    public List<Player> getPlayersByName(String name){
        List<Player> response = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Team t : this.getTeams()) {
            var foundPlayers = t.getSquad().stream()
                    .filter(o -> o.getName().contains(name) || o.getSurname().contains(name))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            response.addAll(foundPlayers);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Ahora bien, te puedo sugerir un par de cambios adicionales para que, usando toda la potencia de los `Stream`s te evites tener que usar un `for` y variables temporales como `response`.

```
    public List<Player> getPlayersByName2(String name){
        return getTeams().stream()
                .flatMap(t -> t.getSquad().stream())// convierte el stream de Team en un stream de Player
                .filter(o -> o.getName().contains(name) || o.getSurname().contains(name))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```